# How can I implement chance/probability into Python?

Tags: python, probability

I want to have Python print "Yes" 70% of the time, and "No" 30% of the time. How should I go about doing so?

Comment: How would you do it manually, e.g. with a pencil and paper?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `random` module:

```
from random import random
while True:
    prob = random()
    if prob >= 0.3:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```